# Flutter does not update when sending Get.to argument when entering the page with other data

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a code like this:

```
Get.to(const ProductDetailsPage(), arguments: [
  {
    "Image": snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["Image"],
  }
]);
```

[image]

For example I enter the top one first and it goes right. But when I leave there and enter the others, the top picture, that is, the first one I entered, remains.

Why could this be? How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

The page where I showed the picture:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:keycehennemi/controllers/PaginationController.dart';

class ProductDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductDetailsPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<ProductDetailsPage> createState() => _ProductDetailsPageState();
}

PaginationController paginationController = PaginationController();

FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

String ImageURL;

dynamic Data = Get.arguments;

class _ProductDetailsPageState extends State<ProductDetailsPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      ImageURL = Data[0]["Image"];
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 2,
        shadowColor: const Color(0xFF94A3B8).withOpacity(0.25),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 25),
            const Center(
              child: Text("Product Details", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Inter Bold", color: Color.fromARGB(255, 226, 226, 226), fontSize: 22),),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Image.network(ImageURL, fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are they StatefulWidgets, by any chance?...

Comment: I am using Stateful Widget. @KarolinaHagegård.

Comment: Well the thing is, when a StatefulWidget is inside a Widget tree, and the tree rebuilds, the StatefulWidget does not get completely rebuilt in the normal case! Only the State gets rebuilt. The "head" so to speak, remains constant. You can force it to rebuild completely by passing a `key` argument to it, however! If you show me how you use your StatefulWidget, I can show you how to use the key.

Comment: I've added my codes to the thread.

Comment: Yes, well, that's the problem... Why is that even a StatefulWidget? Try and make it Stateless! The only place you use setState() is inside the initState() which is right when it's created, anyway!... Plus that's not even allowed... How can that code even run, without crashing?  I can't write much right now, but also try and put `String ImageURL;` and `dynamic Data = Get.arguments;` inside the Widget. We'll talk later!

Comment: I couldn't quite understand what you said because I used a translation. If possible could you post the correct code and the parts you changed? Of course in response.

Comment: Any luck with this, yet?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
So you got an error saying that `Data` was null when you tried calling `Data[0]['Image']`. Plz try the little change I've made between the lines in the code below, and tell me what happens!

Also just try going back and forth between your old code and this new code, making small changes, and see what happens. If you go back completely to your original code that you shared above, does it still work like before? Etc.

---

Try a StatelessWidget instead. It will rebuild fully every time, thus update with the new data.

setState() must NEVER be called inside initState()! This would mean "Rebuild while still being in the process of building the first time".

Also, be careful with putting declarations outside of the class blocks! I.e. outside these braces: { }. Putting declarations on root level like that makes them global, which means they live for as long as the app lives! They are never destroyed. This often gives rise to very weird behavior that you were not expecting. It's better to put declarations inside the block where you want to use them, and send them as arguments to other blocks when needed.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:keycehennemi/controllers/PaginationController.dart';

class ProductDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductDetailsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  PaginationController paginationController = PaginationController();

  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  String ImageURL = 'ImageURL';
  dynamic Data = Get.arguments;  // I've never used this package so I just assume this is the correct way to do it. (I didn't download it to check)

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//--------------------------------------------
    // Replace this:
    // final String ImageURL = Data[0]["Image"];  //This has to be in the build method since it uses "Data", which was declared in initializer and thus can be used in initializer.
    // with this:
    String ImageURL = '';
    if (Data != null) {
      ImageURL = Data[0]["Image"];
    } else {
      print('Data is null');
    }
    print('ImageUrl is $ImageUrl');
//--------------------------------------------

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 2,
        shadowColor: const Color(0xFF94A3B8).withOpacity(0.25),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 25),
            const Center(
              child: Text("Product Details", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Inter Bold", color: Color.fromARGB(255, 226, 226, 226), fontSize: 22),),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Image.network(ImageURL, fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Hello. Thanks for help. I am getting an error: https://imgur.com/a/sk5LTTW

Comment: That error tells you that you tried calling `Data[0]["Image"];` while `Data` had the value Null. That means that your command `dynamic Data = Get.arguments;` didn't work... I'm not sure why, as I'm not familiar with this package, as I said. I can try and look into it, but plz also try yourself! Read the documentation. Also try putting it inside the build method...

Comment: I put some Edits in the answer above. But you should do some more debugging in your end! It's hard to do it like this, when you can't try different things...